# Insert more than one value per row at index

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

I am trying to vectorize the following operation:

- Place a smaller array into a bigger array, whereby the index changes as a function of another array for each row.

Example data:

```py
array_large = [[0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0]] 
array_small = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]] 

array_index = [[1],[0],[2]] #*random index
```

Desired output: `array_combined = [[0,1,2,0,0],[3,4,0,0,0],[0,0,5,6,0]]`

So far I have been getting it to work with apply_along_axis - but I am wondering if there is a more efficient way of solving the problem. I can't seem to wrap my head around the indexing necessary to solve the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use [advanced indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html) here:

```
array_large[np.arange(array_large.shape[0])[:,None], array_index+[0,1]] = array_small
```

Or better, generalizing for whatever shape `array_small` may have:

```
i = np.arange(array_large.shape[0])[:,None]
j = array_index+np.arange(array_small.shape[1])
array_large[i,j] = array_small
```

---

```
print(array_large)

array([[0, 1, 2, 0, 0],
       [3, 4, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 5, 6, 0]])
```

Comment: Thanks @JvdV Just experience in making advanced indexing work, I guess? :)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Thats exactyl what I was looking for :) I was sure there was some solution out there..

Comment: I actually have one more followup question, if its ok: How could this code be apapted if the index in the array_index would be towards the end of the large array, leading to the fact that the small array does not fit. As of now this raises an index error... Can this even be handled for using advanced indexing?

Comment: I think it's better if you post a new question with a simple example ,and the expected output, so it's clearer for everyone @deineomaklaut