# Advanced indexing - managing out of bounds behaviour

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

I am trying to solve the issue of determining the out of bounds behaviour for indexing arrays. For the prior question see: [How can I vectorize dynamically replacing array values with another (smaller) array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61102939/how-can-i-vectorize-dynamically-replacing-array-values-with-another-smaller-ar)

If I have the following sample data:

```
array_large = [[0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0]] 
array_small = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]] 
array_index = [[1],[4],[5]] #*random index
```

Using this code

```
i = np.arange(array_large.shape[0])[:,None]
j = array_index+np.arange(array_small.shape[1])
array_large[i,j] = array_small
```

The behaviour for array_index[0] is clear, but if the index exceeds the target array an error is raised. I would like to ignore invalid indice, but index as much as possible of the smaller array into the larger one. How can I handle for these errors under the consideration that the desired output would be:

```
array_large = [[0,1,2,0,0],[0,0,0,0,3],[0,0,0,0,0]]
```

Comment: Is `array_large` always of zeroes?

Comment: Yes, in my case the large array is always of zeros. I guess a solution padding  the smaller arrays on both ends could also work. I just can't figure it out.

Comment: `np.take` and `np.put` can handle out of bounds values, with several modes (clip, raise, wrap).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can take advantage of the fact that `array_large` is constituted of `0s` to define a mask, and set those indices beyond `array_large.shape[1]` to `0`, as well as their corresponding value in `array_small`:

```
i = np.arange(array_large.shape[0])[:,None]
j = array_index+np.arange(array_small.shape[1])
m = j<array_large.shape[1]
array_large[i,j*m] = array_small*m
```

---

```
print(array_large)

array([[0, 1, 2, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 3],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

Comment: Perfect. I did not know that it is possible to "deselect" indices using a boolean array. That is such a neat solution. Thanks again for your help :)

Comment: Not really deselecting them, just replacing the actual values with `0` @deineomaklaut . You're welcome :)